# mmap: map_anonymous why does it give SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Why does this code segment give segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr=mmap(NULL, 10, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    strcpy(ptr, "Hello");

}
```

Or better, i would like to have: `char *ptr=malloc(10);` then pass this argument to mmap. Both gives SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Check the return values of your system calls!**

The `flags` argument to [`mmap`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/munmap.2.html) must have exactly one of these two options:

```
MAP_SHARED
  Share  this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes
  that map this file, and are carried through to the underlying file. The file
  may not actually  be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.

MAP_PRIVATE
  Create  a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the mapping are not
  visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through
  to the underlying file.   It is  unspecified whether changes made to the file
  after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.
```

You're not providing that, so `mmap` is most likely failing (returning `(void*)-1`) with `errno` set to `EINVAL`.

Comment: +1, relying on segmentation faults as means of diagnostics may not always yield desirable results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved. Now i am using malloc's return value as first argument to mmap, and that worked too. Do you think mapping memories instead of only malloc can be some an overhead?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: yes, potentially a lot. The minimum mapping `mmap` hands out is 1 page (4k on a lot of systems, but can be (much) bigger), so its is not suitable for small allocations (unless you manage smaller chunks inside the mapping yourself. Page table management introduces overhead (for the OS & CPU). Don't think you'll find a quick and cheap way of implementing what you're after, it's hard to do, and near impossible to do "perfectly" - even valgrind can't catch all invalid memory references, and it actually _emulates the complete CPU_.

Comment: Yes, agree. electric-fence does something similar with huge overhead :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably get `MAP_FAILED`  (that is, `(void*)-1`) as the result of your `mmap` with `EINVAL` in `errno`. The [man page of `mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) says that it fails with

```
   EINVAL We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large,
          or not aligned on a page boundary).
```

Your second argument to `mmap` (called `length` in the man page) cannot be 10. It should be a multiple of the page length (at least 4K).

Comment: There is no requirement that `lenght` be a multiple of the page size. (man pages for Linux system calls are much better over at kernel.org than on die.net - they're up to date there, and are actually formatted properly.)